# Javascript regex find all capital letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text and I need to replace every capital letter with something else. I got this working code which replaces every first letter and changes it's color to red.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("each-word")
  for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(/\b([a-z])([a-z]+)?\b/gim, "<span class='first-letter'>$1</span>$2")
  }
```

Is there a way to make it find only capital letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right and you want to replace only capital letters, if they are the first letter of a word, then change your regex to to:

```
/\b([A-Z])([a-z]+)?\b/gm
```

I removed the `i` flag to make it case sensitive and changed the first capturing group to only accept capital letters.

Comment: Thank you both with Guffa, does what I want, can't accept a question just yet as there haven't passed 10min

Comment: @RnD No need to hurry, as long as you don't forget it :)

Comment: Sorry to brother you again, but could you please add a solution for numbers and special characters or point out a good reference?

Comment: [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) is a good source of information as well as the various online tools ([regex](http://www.regex101.com)/[debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com)). For example, if you want numbers/special chars highlighted at the start of a word change `[A-Z]` to `[A-Z0-9!"§$%&/]` and add/remove every special you want/don't want.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `i` switch from the regular expression to make it case-sensitive,
and use capital letters for the first character:

```
/\b([A-Z])([a-z]+)?\b/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = //string
for(i in elements){
    if(i >= 'A' && i <= 'Z')
        //something else
}
```

If we would say, that the elements are just strings, what in fact isn't, but I think this should give you the right idea.